# How long does it take for new Log Sources to take effect?

Tags: .net, logging, event-log, eventlog-source

The [EventLog.Source Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.source.aspx) docs on MSDN state:

> Create the new event source during the
>   installation of your application. This
>   allows time for the operating system
>   to refresh its list of registered
>   event sources and their configuration.

How long does 'allows time' mean?  I've added new Log Sources for our application on a test server but I'm still getting "Tracing to LogSource 'Information' failed" errors.

By the way I'm using `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource` to create my sources; I see that the MSDN docs talk about this being "similar" to using the `EventLogInstaller` but don't elaborate on the differences [sigh].  Does it matter?

```
if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(source))
{
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, "Application");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on how busy the server is until it processes the message/command to add the source. I recommend that you just ignore errors in your application until it works. The second time your application run it should be available right away. I know that's not a great solution (to ignore errors). You could of course retry the trace action until it works (with some timeout and small delay in the loop) if you really depend on the trace messages to be in the event log at startup.